# returning failure code as enum in C++ seems to make code verbose

Tags: c++, error-handling

I'm used to old-school programming whereby functions return 0 for success, non-zero for error, and can be tested easily with

```
if ( ! myobject.mymethod() ) {
    handle error
}
```

So I'm using C++17 for the moment (though I could move forward or back) and chose to make a large number of methods return an enumeration.

So now the compiler complains there's no ! operator.  Fair enough.  **But what is standard practice to avoid having people type:**

```
if ( myobject.mymethod() != ReturnCode::Success ) {
    handle error
}
```

which makes code harder to read and write, I think, increasing total cost of ownership (TCO)?

Just some things I'm considering:

1. define an `operator!(bool)` for all such enums I write in my career going forward.  But I don't recall ever seeing this in other code.
2. use preprocessor definitions of int's instead, and return those (though there's a cost in not being able to understand error 5, say, in the debugger, and having to search headers to see what 5 means
3. exceptions are too big a solution for my needs though I've considered that

Comment: I wouldn't say it makes the code harder to read, to write maybe, depends on how many extra key strokes it requires to do so in your IDE.

Comment: Within C++, a common idiom is things like ReturnCodes are explicitly convertible to `bool`, and `true` indicates "good state" or "success", and `false` indicates "bad state" or "failure".  Although the idiom is common, it is not *standard* and there are tons of counter examples even within the standard C++ library.  (In Unix, *programs* often return 0 for **success** and 1 (or anything other than 0) for **failure**.)

Comment: That may be a common idiom, @Eljay, but it is yet more common for success to be 0 and failure to be other values: the Anna Karenina principle!  To paraphrase: "All happy return codes are alike; each unhappy return code is unhappy in its own way."

Comment: Unfortunately, in C++, the Anna Karenina principle is commonly violated.

Answer (score 1):

If you use simple enum use 0 as Success then you can write code as following:

```
if(!functionCall())
   error handling
```

Or you can read about std::error_code, it has bool operator

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that

```
if ( myobject.mymethod() != ReturnCode::Success ) {
    handle error
}
```

is *much* clearer and less error-prone code than

```
if ( ! myobject.mymethod() ) {
    handle error
}
```

In the former, it is clear from reading this code that the block is handling the non-successful case.

In the latter, you have no idea whether the block is handling success or error or something else, and it is easy for programmers to mix this up.

You actually prove this yourself, you write that returning `0`(false) is success, but your code is treating this as failure.

So don't be afraid of more verbose code, as this helps you avoid errors like this.

Comment: I wouldn't contradict that it has a clear benefit as you describe.  Given the omnipresence of such checks, though,  by declaring the enum as an unscoped enumeration type (i.e., with `enum`) you can just write `!= Success` and I wonder what advantage there would be to using the scoped enumeration (`enum class`) in this case?

Comment: @SwissFrank The advantage to using the scoped enum is type safety and guarding against name clashes. You can always write `using enum Result` in certain blocks to avoid the `Result::` part (requires C++20).

Comment: How does scoped enum give me type safety?  Doesn't the compiler refuse to compile anything where there are name clashes?  In such rare circumstances where someone else is ALSO using an unscoped enum value Success, can't I just add the Result:: part in those few theoretical instances?

Comment: Scoped enum hives you type safety by only being comparable or assignable to other enum of same type, and not to bool or int.

Answer (score 0):

Change `enum class` to `enum` to allow automatic (implicit) conversion to integers, which in turn can be used as boolean values without further work.

Values of *unscoped enumeration type* are implicitly-convertible to integral types.

This *unscoped enumeration type* is what you get by defining the enumeration with `enum`.

Instead, I was using the *scoped* enumeration time, by defining the enumeration using `enum class`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

Comment: You could also change `enum class` to `struct`, and within the `struct` have an `enum Code : int { Success } code;` plus be able to provide all the additional desired behaviors such as a member function `explicit operator bool() const { return code != Success; }`.

Comment: OK, but what is the benefit for that extra complexity?

Comment: The extra complexity of a `struct ReturnCode` can provide the desired functionality in one place rather than have it replicated throughout the code.  Making ReturnCode easier to *use*, at the expense of making ReturnCode itself a little more complex to design and implement.